# Wordpress Woocommerce свой шаблон для определенной категории

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Мне не нужно для всех категорий свой шаблон, только для определенных.

Есть различные категории, в каждой свои товары и товары со своими страницами, которых можно отправит в корзину.

Мне нужна одна категория товаров, у которых нет своих страниц, есть только название, вес, цена, количество и нужна кнопка "в корзину". Я хочу сделать обычную таблицу и вывести все товары из такой категории. Как это можно сделать?

Гугл показывает только, как изменить шаблон для всех категорий товаров на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ:

```
global $wp_query;
$cat_slug = $wp_query->query_vars['product_cat'];
echo $cat_slug;
```

в файле woocommerce/archive-product.php

Он выводит название активной категории, а дальше уже можно в if и нужные действия